# Google Maps. Проблема с последним маркером

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, marker

Создаю маркер на карте, в то же функции есть функция удаления маркера по правому клику(ну или отдельная которая проверяет по `id`, проблема будет та же).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });

    markers.push(marker);

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "rightclick", function (event) {
        markers.splice(marker, 1);
        marker.setMap(null);
   });
});
```

Также есть функция удаления всех сразу

```
var deleteMarkers = function () {
  markers.forEach(function (marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
  });
  markers = [];
}
```

Проблемы нет если удалять все маркеры или по одному, или оставить 2 и более. Но если оставить 1, а потом удалить через `deleteMarkers`, то маркер остается на карте, массив очищается.